# How to run phpBB in Docker with NGINX, php installed on a different host than the database?

Tags: docker, nginx, phpbb3

How can I run a Docker image with NGINX, phpBB (and all required stuff like php installed) with persistence (Changes on the board shouldn't be lost) and with the database on another host (which already exists). So, let's assume I have the following: MySQL on 192.168.2.233 (local address) on port 3307 running. Now I want to create a Docker image with Alpine Linux (The smallest propably), NGINX and phpBB where the board runs on the NGINX webserver and connects to the database. Changes on the board (E.g. changing the webserver settings or so) should be persisted within the container. How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

The database on server 192.168.2.233 is already existing! So no, I don't need two or more Docker containers. I need one Docker container with phpBB running on the NGINX webserver and connecting to the database on another host in the same network. The container should use persistence (volumes) to save the settings made in phpBB.
[image: Example setup]

I tried to use the following Dockerfile and modified it:
https://gitlab.com/boxedcode/alpine-nginx-php-fpm/blob/master/Dockerfile --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CW68OFCJE9RjIe8_RBC8q5Fa6juRtxmR

Comment: Hint: You'll probably want to run the various components in separate containers (e.g. the phpBB app in one, NGINX in another, the DB in another).  To persist your data mount external volumes.  I'd recommend having a go and then re-posting specific questions if you run into problems - you'll get better responses!

Comment: @bunnmat I already have a running instance of the database (See the edited question with the image).

Comment: Does https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/phpbb/ give you what you'd need?

Comment: @bunnmat: If I modify it a bit, I guess so :)

Comment: I've now found a solution using this repository: https://github.com/blueimp/phpbb/issues/1 and put my solution in there together with the owner of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with the owner of another repository I've now found a solution (that uses Apache however) here: https://github.com/blueimp/phpbb/issues/1. After a few errors and problems from my side, I figured it out. The solution I'm using now is placed here: https://github.com/SeppPenner/DockerApacheSSLphpBB